# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no existe la relación «usuarios_usuarios»

Tags: django, postgresql

***Estoy trabajando en mi proyecto de Django, cuando intento hacer mis migraciones python manage.py makemigrations y finalmente python manage.py migrate, me sale todo este error:***

```
Operations to perform:

  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions

Running migrations:

  Applying admin.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in _execute

    return self.cursor.execute(sql)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: no existe la relación «usuarios_usuarios»





The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\centrali_backend\manage.py", line 22, in <module>

    main()

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\centrali_backend\manage.py", line 18, in main

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line

    utility.execute()

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute

    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv

    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute

    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper

    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)

          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 356, in handle

    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(

                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate

    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(

            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards

    state = self.apply_migration(

            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 249, in apply_migration

    with self.connection.schema_editor(

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 166, in __exit__

    self.execute(sql)

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 48, in execute

    return super().execute(sql, None)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 201, in execute

    cursor.execute(sql, params)

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 122, in execute

    return super().execute(sql, params)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute

    return self._execute_with_wrappers(

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers

    return executor(sql, params, many, context)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in _execute

    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__

    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Centrali Software\Backend\entorno\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in _execute

    return self.cursor.execute(sql)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no existe la relación «usuarios_usuarios»



Hice también todo sobre darle permiso a Django para que pueda acceder a mi base de datos, tener usuario, y todo lo demás, realmente no sé qué sucede.
```

***Este es mi archivo base.py:***

```
"""
Django settings for centrali_backend project.
 
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.
 
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/
 
For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""
 
from unipath import Path
 
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)
 
print("=========")
print(BASE_DIR)
 
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/
 
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-zk0nr&+1*+=#s$5%%jvxs&!1^g8lh63hw76ee7g_2u%@=+=ra$'
 
 
 
# Application definition
 
DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
 
LOCAL_APSS = (
    'aplicaciones.usuarios',
)
 
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'rest_framework',
)
 
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APSS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS
 
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
 
ROOT_URLCONF = 'centrali_backend.urls'
 
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
 
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'centrali_backend.wsgi.application'
 
 
 
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
 
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
 
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usuarios.Usuarios'
 
 
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/
 
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
 
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
 
USE_I18N = True
 
USE_TZ = True
 
 
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
 
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

***Mi modelo Usuarios:***

```
from django.db import models
 
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
 
from .managers import UsuarioManager
 
class Usuarios(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    activo_con_email_password = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    
    codigo_activar_cuenta = models.CharField(
        max_length = 8, 
        unique = True, 
        null = True,
        blank = True
        )
    
    codigo_recuperar_cuenta = models.CharField(
        max_length = 8,
        unique = True, 
        null = True,
        blank = True
        )
 
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    
 
    objeto = UsuarioManager()
 
    def get_name(self):
 
        return self.nombre
 
class Configuracion(models.Model):
 
    restriccion_cuenta_empleados = models.BooleanField(default = False)


Directorio del proyecto:
```

***Este es mi directorio del proyecto Django:***

C:.

├───centrali_backend

│   ├───aplicaciones

│   │   └───usuarios

│   └───centrali_backend

│       └───settings

***Ya he intentado borrar la base de datos, volver a crearla pero da el mismo error, es raro que al hacer el makemigrations diga que no hay nuevos cambios.***

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. ¿Te fijaste si tus archivos de migraciones están haciendo algún tipo de conflicto?